# Autoresponder Contact Form 7

Tags: contact-form

Below is the code for my contact form. I need to send an auto responder email , what should I put in the To field. I have tried using [usermail] or [Email] , but every time it says configuration error.

Name *

```
        <p> <label for="usermail" class="iconic mail-alt"> E-mail address <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="email" name="usermail" id="usermail" /> </p>
        <p> <label for="subject" class="iconic quote-alt"> Subject </label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"  /> </p>
        <p> <label for="message" class="iconic comment"> Message  <span class="required">*</span></label> <textarea name="message" required="required" ></textarea> </p>
        <p class="indication"> All fields with a <span class="required">*</span> are required</p>           
        <input type="submit" value=" ★  Shoot !" />
```

Comment: Describe more your question hard to understand about configuration background work how you configure it if you really need help ask in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask manner

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I am actually facing problem while setting up the auto responder email using Contact Form 7 plugin. In the "To" field of the mail , I need to put the user email to which the mail will be sent out. I have given the HTML of my contact form above. I am not sure which mail tag to use in the "To" field. I have tried using ["usermail"] , [usermail] , everytime it says syntax error in the field.

Comment: You can edit your question instead comment